# Can't load a photo in my java example

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, nullpointerexception, imageicon

I'm trying to do this example
http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javagamestutorial/movingsprites/
but i get these errors

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(Unknown Source)
at rtype.Craft.<init>(Craft.java:19)
at rtype.board.<init>(board.java:28)
at rtype.Rtype.<init>(Rtype.java:9)
at rtype.Rtype.main(Rtype.java:20)
```

I have tried putting my image in various places inside my project file
and even writing the absolute path.

What do i do wrong?
I use eclipse.

edit: Excuse me here's the code

```
private String craft = "craft.png";

private int dx;
private int dy;
private int x;
private int y;
private Image image;

public Craft() {
    ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("C:\\Users\\Name\\workspace\\Craft\\src\\resource\\craft.png"));
    image = ii.getImage();
    x = 40;
    y = 60;
}
```

This one above is my current try while the example suggests:

```
ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(craft));
```

Comment: please show some code

Comment: Could you be more specific about how are you trying to load photo? Some your not working code example?

Comment: You definitely need to add some code so that we can help

Comment: We need to see the relevant part of **your** code.

Comment: simply write: `ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Name\\workspace\\Craft\\src\\resource\\craft.png");`

Comment: In your project create a res folder... Make sure it is the same level as the src folder.. Access the image by using "res/Craft.png" note: I am assuming your picture is name Craft.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this.getClass().getResource` is mainly used if you run code from jar file and you need to load resources that are also inside jar.

In your case you should probably just load it as

```
ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Name/workspace/Craft/src/resource/craft.png");
image = ii.getImage();
```

or maybe even

```
ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon("craft.png");
image = ii.getImage();
```

if your image is inside of your project.

Comment: Well now i don't have any errors but neither do i have a craft. There is just a black background. I think it's perhaps my image's fault. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Rentonie try `right-click on your project` -> `New` -> `folder` (set name to imgs) -> `Finish`, move your image to this folder and try to load it with `new ImageIcon("imgs/craft.png");`

Comment: Yes, it worked as charm. Thanks you very much but how did it solve it now?

Answer (score 2):

The exception is thrown from `ImageIcon` constructor. Looks from the sample like `ImageIcon` is initialized with `URL`, this [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html#ImageIcon%28java.net.URL%29):

```
String craft = "craft.png";
...
ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(craft));
```

The reason is probably due to the missing file "craft.png" in your workspace. Make sure that loader can find the specified file and `this.getClass().getResource(craft)` is not null.

See [Loading Images Using getResource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html#getresource) tutorial for details and some examples how to add and load images and other resources.